# Is there a method to forcibly pass a non-responsive function?

Tags: python

Sorry if this is obvious. I have never had this problem before. I have a loop that calls a problematic function. 99% of the time the function returns a string correctly. The other 1%, it does nothing at all. It does not raise any errors, it does not return anything, it does not allow my code to continue to the next line. I had considered executing the loop in one thread and a timer in another thread with the hopes of terminating the thread that has the loop, but I've read that you have to wait for a thread to finish before it can close. Does anyone know a method to either forcibly terminate a thread or forcibly continue onto some other line when the code is hung up?

When I interrupt the code I get a call back the specific line in the library that it hangs up on, but I'm not experienced enough to confidently go in and problem solve someone else's functions like that.

To clarify, I'm looking for a work around. Not a fix for the function I'm calling.

I don't think it will help, but here's the loop in question

```
while(True):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    FEN_board = [["","","","","","","",""],["","","","","","","",""],["","","","","","","",""],["","","","","","","",""],\
    ["","","","","","","",""],["","","","","","","",""],["","","","","","","",""],["","","","","","","",""],]

    t1 = threading.Thread(target = find_white_pieces)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target = find_black_pieces)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

    print(create_FEN())
    FEN = create_FEN()
    FEN = FEN + ' w'
    stockfish.set_fen_position(FEN)
    
    move = stockfish.get_best_move() # <---- The function that halts my code completely

    print(move)
    print(f"Completed in:  {time.perf_counter() - start} seconds")
```

File "c:\Users\tomma\Desktop\code stuff\python files\scratch_work.py", line 165, in     move = stockfish.get_best_move()  File "C:\Users\tomma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\stockfish\models.py", line 257, in get_best_move    text = self._read_line()  File "C:\Users\tomma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\stockfish\models.py", line 109, in _read_line    return self._stockfish.stdout.readline().strip()  File "C:\Users\tomma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 22, in decode    def decode(self, input, final=False):KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: How could you possibly expect us to help you debug code you don't show us?

Comment: I'm not asking for a debug, I'm asking for a workaround. Some sort of known way to either recognize when a line of code has hung up, or to forcibly terminate a section of code that doesn't return anything or continue onto the next line

Comment: Procedural languages simply don't work like that. If possible, you might be able to use async programming to let that function run while also timing it, but that may be difficult to do depending on the `stockfish.get_best_move()` function's implementation (and whether you have access to it).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand your question. If it returns nothing, do you mean it returns a Nonetype object or an empty string.

Because in such a case you just do

```
if func() == np.nan() or func() == '':
    continue
```

If it throws an error, you could do

```
try:
    func()
except:
    continue
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry, poor wording on my part. It's not that it returns a none type, but that it doesn't return anything at all. Without really knowing what's going on, I would describe it as though the function I'm calling executes another program that enters an infinite loop and cannot return anything to the function I'm calling. The function I'm calling doesn't raise any errors for me to use try: except: and it doesn't return a None type or empty string.